# Rails error undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass in my controller

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I had some problems with my Ruby on Rails code.  The error is: `undefined method`name' for nil:NilClass`.

Migration:

```
class CreateFeedbacks < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :feedbacks do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.text :body
      t.references :user, index: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Feedback model:

```
class Feedback < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

User model:

```
has_many :feedbacks
```

File: `app/controllers/feedback_controller.rb`:

```
class FeedbacksController < ApplicationController    
  def index
    @feedback = Feedback.all
  end

  def create
    @feedback = @user.feedbacks.build(feedback_params)
    @feedback = Feedback.find(params[:id])
    if @feedback.save
      redirect_to my_profile_path
    end
  end

  def new
    @feedback = Feedback.new
  end

  def show
    @feedback = Feedback.find(params[:id])
  end

  private
  def feedback_params
    params.require(:feedback).permit(:name, :body)
  end
end
```

File: `views/feedbacks/_feedback.html.erb`

```
<div class="info-frame-feedbacks">
  <p><strong><%= @feedback.name %></strong></p>
  <p><%= @feedback.body %></p>
  <p><%= time_ago_in_words(feedback.created_at) %> Ago</p>

  <h4>Add feedback:</h4>
  <%= render "feedbacks/form" %>
</div>
```

File: `views/feedbacks/_form.html.erb``

```
<%= form_for ([@user, @user.feedbacks.build]) do |f| %>
    <p>
      <%= f.label :name %><br>
      <%= f.text_field :name %>
    </p>
    <p>
      <%= f.label :body %><br>
      <%= f.text_area :body %>
    </p>
    <br>
    <p>
      <%= f.submit %>
    </p>
<% end %>
```

And the view renders the partial:

```
<%= render "feedbacks/feedback" %>
```

Console log:

> > ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass):
> >         1: <div class="info-frame-feedbacks">
> >         2:   <p><strong><%= @feedback.name %></strong></p>
> >         3:   <p><%= @feedback.body %></p>
> >         4:   <p><%= time_ago_in_words(feedback.created_at) %> Ago</p>
> >         5:    app/views/feedbacks/_feedback.html.erb:2:in`_app_views_feedbacks__feedback_html_erb__96950790565369491_70223374345140'   app/views/profiles/_photographer_profile.html.erb:62:in
> >     `_app_views_profiles__photographer_profile_html_erb__2595614421496138366_70223370764320'
> >     app/views/profiles/my_profile.html.erb:1:in`
> >     _app_views_profiles_my_profile_html_erb___130517334733103876_70223370684660'
>
> Rendered
>   /home/vlad/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (1.5ms)   Rendered
>   /home/vlad/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb
>   (1.1ms)   Rendered
>   /home/vlad/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/template_error.html.erb
>   within rescues/layout (14.4ms)

Comment: @feedback is `nil`. Meaning that it was not set in the controller.

Comment: You also don't have any code to set @user in create.

Comment: Please add the Rails log for the action that's failing.  The log should contain everything between `Started` and `Completed`, including the entire error message and backtrace.  You can click the `edit` button directly below your answer (above these comments) to add the new information to your question.

Comment: consol log +. Tell me pls what i should to do

Comment: @VladyslavKalyuzhnyy You pasted a portion of the console log.  Can you please post everything for the action, starting with `Started` and ending with `Completed` from the log?  Just the action that's failing, but the entire log for that action.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of things wrong.

You have the wrong code to populate @feedback in the `create` action handler.  Simply replace this:

```
@feedback = Feedback.find(params[:id])
```

with this:

```
@feedback = Feedback.new
```

You are also missing the `edit` action in your controller, so it defaults to just rendering the `edit` view.  You need to set the @feedback variable there.

Try adding this into your controller, just below the `new` action handler:

```
def edit
  @feedback = Feedback.find(params[:id])
end
```

That should do it.

Comment: Replace + and adding "edit" + too but the same problem "undefined method 'name' " =(